# How to get result from external application's activity?

Tags: android

How to get result from an external application's activity so that my application that has triggered it could know the change.

For e.g:

My application needs to check if user has been logged in. If not logged in, it allows to login through external app.

So current app. would call onActivityForResult() to trigger external App's activity and 
onActivityResult() will be called processing the exit status of external App's activity.

---

Solved.

Sorry for my goof up.

I have realized that I made mistakes for entire session  of testing.
My understanding and code were fine, but ***every time I made changes to both
the files, I never ran the external app. with updated code***.

Even I found the solution myself, i am considering Nanne's answer as my hint to solution, thus marked as accepted answer.

Thanks and sorry for ur precious time.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? It's done the way you just described. You call startActivityForResult(). External app's Activity does its thing, set the return values, and you process those values in your own Activity in onActivityResult() upon finishing. If the external app doesn't give you the return values you need and you can't modify that app, then it's a dead end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity you've started should set a result-value with `setResult(intValue)`

Your first activity, that called `startActivityForResult()` can check this result with the code provided [in the example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
         Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             //do something
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the code that is useful to u for one app to another app

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent res = new Intent();
        String mPackage = "com.ReachOut";
        String mClass = ".splash1";
        res.setComponent(new ComponentName(mPackage,mPackage+mClass));
        startActivity(res);
    }
});
```

Comment: Any third party that wants you to access their activities will provide stable Intent patterns for you to follow. The code shown here is likely to break when the third-party app gets updated -- please do not use this approach.